# Is there a way to ignore acronyms in a title case method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**Background**

I have a list of TV programs that I want to convert to title case. My current code works well on programs like "bojack Horseman," "Family GUY," and "jessica jones." However, some of my programs have acronyms in them. As a result, a title like "paradise pd" would be converted to "Paradise Pd."

I've looked into Regex as a possible solution and visited some sites, notably (Regex101)[https://regex101.com/] to see if I could find something. Maybe I am not using the correct search terms in their library, but I didn't have luck there.

Is that the best solution for what I am looking to do or is there a better way?

**My Code As It Stands**

```
titleSort = () => {
    // make sure all program names are in title case
    let titleCasePrograms = this.props.programs.map(program => program.name.split(' ')
        .map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1).toLowerCase())
        .join(' '))
}
```

**What I Hope to Accomplish**

The code above is part of a larger batch that I am writing to sort the names alphabetically. Before I get to the actual sorting method, however, I want to make sure I'm taking different types of words into account that I'll come across and formatting them properly. :-)

#### Thank You Very Much for Your Time and Advice!

Comment: Ah, this needs to be checked on a directory... Not sure if you can automate it without data.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I'm not sure what you mean. Should I add something to my post?

Comment: Like how the answer given, you gotta use a dictionary like `['PD', 'MD', 'ASAP', 'NCIS']; // ...etc....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computer has no way of knowing what an acronym is, so you'll need to have a list of acronyms. Once you have that, you can just add a check against that list to your transformation. Something like this:

```
const acronyms = ['PD', 'MD', 'ASAP', 'NCIS']; // ...etc....
titleSort = () => {
    let titleCasePrograms = this.props.programs.map(program => {
        return program.name.split(' ')
                          .map(w => {
                              if (acronyms.includes(w.toUpperCase())) {
                                  return w.toUpperCase();
                              }
                              return w[0].toUpperCase() + w.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                          })
                          .join(' ')
    );
}
```

Comment: Usually acronyms are separated by a period, e.g P.D, M.A.S.H, etc. In addition to IceMetal's answer, you can maybe check against a list of known acronyms and massage your data to format your acronyms this way.

Answer (score 1):

Super late, but I had a similar issue and handled it this way. The definition I've set for acronyms in my case is any word with two capital letters in it.

This means it'll handle "ABC", "A.B.C.", "AofBofC". It's got a bit of edge handling, but you'll probably still want to mind your spelling. It's simplistic, but whatever, I hope it helps someone out.

```js
const str = "Lorem ABC Dolor Sit Amet, RCMP Adipiscing Elit, TBS Do Eiusmod Tempor R.C.M.P. Ut Labore Et IO Magna Aliqua.";

//Helper function, sentence case strings, excluding acronyms
function toSentenceCase (str) {
  
  //Helper function to manage a single sentence
  function caseHandler(str){
    let arr = str.split(' ');
    
    //Test each word to see if an acronym
    return arr.map(function(item, i){
      //If not the first word
      if(i > 0 ){
        //Test with regex for acronym, if true, leave alone
        if(/[A-Z].*[A-Z]+.*/.test(item)){
          return item;
        }
        //If not an acronym, titlecase the word
        else {
          return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
        } 
      }
      //If the first word, titlecase the word
      else {
        return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
      }
    }).join(' ')
  }

  //Splits strings by sentence
  const stringsArr = str.split('. ')
  //Temp arr
  let sentenceArr = [];
  //Loop through sentences
  stringsArr.forEach(function(item) {
    //For each sentence, call our caseHandler, push result to temp arr
    sentenceArr.push(caseHandler(item))
  })
  //Join the array the same way that we split the string
  return sentenceArr.join('. ')
}

const name = document.querySelector("#app");
name.textContent = toSentenceCase(str);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```